# Searching for free requirements management software

Tags: requirements, requirements-management

I am looking for a requirements management software, like DOORS, but for free *(I need to enter requirements, and generate a specification document, not only follow requirement traceability like reqtify allows you to do)*
I searched on the Internet, and I found the nearly perfect sofware : **GenSpec**. Moreover, GenSpec use templates with standards, like IEEE 830 which is the one I am interested in.

I said "nearly perfect" because the document generation does not work in GenSpec (runtime error). So I tried to subscribe to the google group to ask some assistance, but I think it is an old software which is not supported and updated anymore (for info, I downloaded GenSpec 6.8.40 and I work with Microsoft Office 2016, I think there is a compatibility issue, but it is only an hypothesis)

So I am posting this subject here if someone can :

- Either tell me if there is a similar software ?
- Or, knows GenSpec and
  can perhaps help me with my document generation issue (I could give
  more details in this case) ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can take a look at ReqFlow http://goeb.github.io/reqflow/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a similar SW - ReqView. See the SW Recommendations question at 
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/52607/41086

Comment: 360$ per user/year is NOT free!

Comment: Well, ReqView is a freemium. With the FREE plan you can edit a single specification document (e.g. SRS), up to 150 objects and a single custom attribute (e.g. status). That should cover most personal / educational usecases. Your feedback on the FREE plan is welcome, I am leading ReqView development.

Comment: Hi libor, thanks for your answer. I read your link and I saw the document generation is not a feature of this software but it seems to be easy to implement. I will try the software, thank you